# Office 365 API. issue sharing files

Tags: azure, office365, onedrive

I have an error message while trying to share a file that i already know the Id.
Environment :
I got the Application token, so I can print the drive information, also I can list the root children. but when i try to generate the sharing link I get error message bellow.
help please :)
NB : I'm doing all that staff in PostMan
here is my POST Request :

```
https://visiativsoftware-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/me/drive/items/016F...NKH/action.createLink
Header:
Content-Type : application/json
body:
Authorization=Bearer eyJ0eXAi...U9DQhKoA
type=view
scope=organization
```

and here is the response

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
    "message": "Accès refusé. Vous n’êtes pas autorisé à effectuer cette action ou à accéder à cette ressource."
  }
}
```

Comment: Did the application has the write permission to the item?

Comment: thank you so much for answering. How can i verify that ? the admin gave me full control of the app but don't know how to do that for files or directories.

Comment: one more detail : i can make GET requests but not POST or DELETE

Comment: When you register the app with Azure AD we need to config the permissions. We need to config the `Read and Write user files` as the figure like [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/app-registration.htm#register-your-app-for-onedrive-for-business) mentioned.

Comment: permissions are all OK in this section